# Small Caps in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to figure out how to use small caps in text areas in AS3.

Right now I'm doing a work around were i wrote a function that replaces lower case letters with a capital letter in a smaller font size. This works OK, however the real Small Caps glyphs that are included in the font look better.

There is a reference here:

public static const CAPS_AND_SMALL_CAPS:String = "capsAndSmallCaps"

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/engine/TypographicCase.html

however, I can't figure out how to apply it to a text area.

Comment: ended up just editing the font and replacing all the lower case letters with small caps, flash is terrible at handling fonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flex, you can do it through CSS or directly through MXML for the Label class.

```
.className {
    typographicCase: "capsToSmallCaps";
}
```

or

```
<s:Label styleName="className" typographicCase="capsToSmallCaps"/>
```

It doesn't appear you can set `typographicCase` on a standard `TextField`, however. Looks like you need to use different components in order to utilize it. See [this Adobe document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS9dd7ed846a005b294b857bfa122bd808ea6-7ffa.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use styles in action script, I would suggest you use `font-variant: small-caps` for the text areas.

Comment: I tried this. Font-variant isn't a CSS property that is supported by flash.